# MTconnect C++ Agent Run Sample Failed

Tags: c#, c++, mtconnect

I am testing MTConnect C++ Agent Version 2.1 from [github](https://github.com/mtconnect/cppagent). And using Pre-built binary releases for Windows. From the documentation, I found that I can run the agent from this command, under the bin folder where these two files are already exsits. :

```
agent.exe run agent.cfg
```

But as I run this it creates a log file below given errors

> 2023-03-15T10:29:55.419359Z (0x000025e4) [info]
> MAIN->AgentConfiguration::initialize->AgentConfiguration::loadConfig:
> Starting agent on port 5000 2023-03-15T10:29:55.425344Z (0x000025e4)
> [warning]
> MAIN->AgentConfiguration::initialize->AgentConfiguration::loadConfig->AgentConfiguration::loadSinks:
> The following path "../styles\old" is not a regular file:
> "D:\@TLL_Docs\MTConnect\MTConnectCPPAgentVersion2\cppagent-2.1.0.6-win64\styles\old"
> 2023-03-15T10:29:55.426341Z (0x000025e4) [info]
> MAIN->AgentConfiguration::initialize->AgentConfiguration::loadConfig->Agent::initialize->Agent::loadXMLDeviceFile:
> MTConnect Schema Version of file:
> D:@TLL_Docs\MTConnect\MTConnectCPPAgentVersion2\cppagent-2.1.0.6-win64\bin../simulator/VMC-3Axis.xml
> = 2.0 2023-03-15T10:29:55.433323Z (0x000025e4) [info] MAIN->AgentConfiguration::initialize->AgentConfiguration::loadConfig->AgentConfiguration::loadAdapters:
> shdr: Adding adapter for VMC-3Axis: VMC-3Axis
> 2023-03-15T10:29:55.434320Z (0x000025e4) [debug] MAIN: Waiting for
> monitor thread to exit to restart agent 2023-03-15T10:29:55.434320Z
> (0x000025e4) [debug] MAIN->AgentConfiguration::monitorThread:
> Monitoring files:
> "D:\@TLL_Docs\MTConnect\MTConnectCPPAgentVersion2\cppagent-2.1.0.6-win64\bin\agent.cfg"
> and
> D:@TLL_Docs\MTConnect\MTConnectCPPAgentVersion2\cppagent-2.1.0.6-win64\bin../simulator/VMC-3Axis.xml,
> will warm start if they change. 2023-03-15T10:29:55.434320Z
> (0x000025e4) [debug] MAIN->AgentConfiguration::monitorThread: Setting
> device and config times 2023-03-15T10:29:55.435318Z (0x00004ebc)
> [debug] Connector::resolved->Connector::connect: Connecting to data
> source: 127.0.0.1 on port: 7878 2023-03-15T10:29:57.486013Z
> (0x00004ebc) [error] Connector::connected: No connection could be made
> because the target machine actively refused it: No connection could be
> made because the target machine actively refused it
> 2023-03-15T10:29:58.486920Z (0x00004ebc) [info] : reconnect: retrying
> connection

I think that i need an adapter (server) for it but I don't know how to do this? At least how run the MTConnect C++ Agent

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: The default agent.cfg configuration tries to connect to an MTConnect adapter on the local machine (127.0.0.1) port 7878. The cppagent repo at https://github.com/mtconnect/cppagent contains a `simulator` folder with a Ruby script that simulates the default VMC-3Axis machine.